# Add text to gif that changes with every new added image

Tags: windows, imagemagick, animated-gif

I would like to add text to a gif, that would change with every new image. The goal is to display elapsed time. The formula would be something simple, like: "number of image" x "time elapsed per image".

Edit:
I am using a windows os.

Comment: You can add text to images with ImageMagick, but to do wat you want you would have to call IM from a script that calls IM with  the text for each imahe, obtained by some other way. Scripting is going to be different if on Linux/OSX or Windows, so you have to specify this.

Comment: Hi, I updated the question with the specified os, which is Windows 10.